# Tkinter - unable to move polygon on the screen

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm learning Python and I decided to make a GUI. It's a simple GUI that'll just move a polygon on the screen.  But it seems the thread keep getting stuck in the `update` method.

```
class main():

    render = Render(500, 500)

    while True:
        render.update()
        time.sleep(1)


class Render:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.config(height=500, width=500)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = width, height = height, 
                             background = "white")
        self.deltaX = 0


    def update(self):
        print(self.deltaX)
        self.canvas.create_polygon(150 + self.deltaX, 75, 225 + self.deltaX, 0, 
                                   300 + self.deltaX, 75, 225 + self.deltaX, 150, 
                                   outline = "black", fill = "")
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.window = mainloop()
        self.deltaX += 10
        return None
```

Sorry if this is dumb, but I'm very new to Python.

Comment: Moving a polygon on the screen is not as simple as you seem to think. I suggest you try something easier until you've learned Python better. Besides that, using `tkinter` to make a GUI can also be difficult to learn, even if you know Python well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call mainloop like that, probably you should only call it once. See [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways to write this out. No matter how you do it you only need to call/draw the object once and then update it through your loop

It can be as simple as creating a property in the constructor and then updating via a method

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class Render:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.config(height=500, width=500)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = width, height = height, 
                             background = "white")
        self.deltaX = 2
        self.poly = self.canvas.create_polygon(150 + self.deltaX, 75, 225 + self.deltaX, 0, 
                                   300 + self.deltaX, 75, 225 + self.deltaX, 150, 
                                   outline = "black", fill = "")
        self.canvas.pack()
    def update(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.poly, self.deltaX, 0)
        self.window.update()    


class main():

    render = Render(500, 500)

    while True:
        render.update()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving one or more objects in `tk.Canvas` is fairly easy.

Here is an interactive demo that enables one or more objects to be positioned with simple left mouse button click.

It uses `tags` to name the object|s and `event_add` to bind multiple keyboard|mouse activity to function `pickNplace`

```py
master = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width = 600, height = 400)
canvas.grid(sticky = tk.NSEW)
xx = yy = moveit = 0

def pickNplace(event):
    global moveit, xx, yy
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    if event.num == 1:
        moveit = 1 - moveit
    if moveit:
        canvas.move("poly", x - xx, y - yy)
    xx, yy = x, y

canvas.event_add("<<MOVER>>", "<Motion>", "<ButtonRelease-1>")
canvas.bind("<<MOVER>>", pickNplace)

canvas.create_polygon(
    0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100,
    fill = "blue", outline = "blue", tags = "poly")

master.mainloop()
```